# ES6 format date

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My api gives me

```
2016-09-01T11:12:31
```

I want this to be 01 SEPTEMBER 2016. How can I accomplish that?

When using jquery I could use the $.format, but I have no clue right now. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You can either parse it as you want, or use a library like Moment.js. http://momentjs.com

Comment: jQuery doesn't have `$.format` but maybe it was a plugin. So just search for a different date formatting library if you want a pre-made API, or write a few lines of code that'll give you the format you want.

Comment: ```(d=>`${('0'+d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)} ${['JANUARY', 'FEBRUARY', …][d.getUTCMonth()]} ${d.getUTCFullYear()}`)(new Date(apistring+'Z'))```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new Date object passing your API returns: `new Date("2016-09-01T11:12:31")`, then you can use functions like `getDay()`, `getMonth()`, `getYear()`.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: W3Schools is not a good general source. You'd be much better off directing people to MDN.